# F# Anonymous Records error (unmatched/unexpected) - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: f#, record, anonymous

Hello I have problem with code from F# class. I have VS2019 with F# and .NET package everything was working until anomymous records.

```
type Student = {
imie: string;
nazwisko: string;
wiek:int;
rokStudiow:int;
```

}

```
  let dane = [
        {imie="Kowalska"; nazwisko="AA"; wiek=21; rokStudiow = 1};
        {imie="Nowak"; nazwisko="BB"; wiek=31;rokStudiow = 2};              // musza byc sredniki
        {imie="Adamski";nazwisko="CC"; wiek=41; rokStudiow = 3};            // kolekcja studentow
        {imie="Kot";nazwisko="DD"; wiek=51; rokStudiow = 2};
        {imie="Konopnicki";nazwisko="EE"; wiek=21; rokStudiow=2}
    ]
```

```
    let wynik = List.map (fun o -> { | imie=o.imie;nazwisko=o.nazwisko | }) dane
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple syntax error.

Anonymous records are written as
`let foo = {| a=1; b="hi" |}` You inserted a space between the curly braces and the pipes.

Just change your assignment to

`let wynik = List.map (fun o -> {| imie=o.imie;nazwisko=o.nazwisko |}) dane`

and you should be good to go.

(BTW, you have a lot of redundant semicolons in your code. For example, you can skip all semicolons in your definition of `type Student`
Also, a more idiomatic f# statement would be

`let wynik = dane |> List.map (fun o -> {| imie=o.imie;nazwisko=o.nazwisko |})`

That is purely a matter of style though.)